# Introduction to Anderson localization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, anderson-localization

I find Anderson's [original paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRev.109.1492) too terse. I am looking for something that introduces me gently to the subject so that I can understand Anderson's paper and other literature. What references are out there that introduce [Anderson localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson_localization)? Anything will work for me: lecture notes, review papers, introductory papers ...

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/180544/13917

Comment: YouTube video: [What is Anderson Localization?](https://youtu.be/TvD0zbF7z5U?feature=shared)

Answer (score 5):

I do not know much about books on Anderson localization but there was a conference some time ago celebrating the $50$ years on the proposal by Anderson in which you can find many useful references. The list is [here](http://www.andersonlocalization.com/canonal50.php#Anderson_Model).

I can recommend you the course by van Tiggelen. He's quite an expert in this subject and Les Houches lectures tend to be very pedagogical.

There is also a book with the same title than the workshop but a bit more recent:

[$50$ years of Anderson localization, E. Abrahams](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814299065)

The first chapter is written by P. W. Anderson himself.

Comment: I am reading something called "Localization of waves" by van Tiggelen. Are these the lectures? I have to say they seem more like a review than an introduction to the subject. It's full of references, which is good, but I was looking for something more like an introduction, textbook style.

Comment: Yes, I was refering to that ones. Perhaps, although is not specific to Anderson localization but closely related you can have a look to [Mesoscopic Physics of Electrons and Photons](http://www.amazon.com/Mesoscopic-Physics-Electrons-Photons-Akkermans/dp/0521349478/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1365533951&sr=1-1) or the books in the references below.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what has already been said I would add:

1. The original paper is at this point historical; you are right to look for other sources.
2. You should also read about [weak localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_localization#cite_note-2) and [coherent backscattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_backscattering) which are closely related.
3. A good reference is Chapter 5 of the 1st edition [Electronic Transport in Mesoscopic Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521599431) by S. Datta.

Answer (score 3):

> This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

---

- [Fluctuations And Localization In Mesoscopic Electron Systems](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4335)
- [Introduction to Wave Scattering, Localization and Mesoscopic Phenomena](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540291555)